# Mocking an extension function with Mockito

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, mockito

How can I test an extension function with Mockito? It doesn't seem to work nicely.

This is my extension function

```
fun <T> CrudRepository<T, String>.findOneById(id: String): T? {
    val o = findById(id)
    return if (o.isPresent) o.get() else null
}
```

And this is what I'm trying to test

```
  @Test
    fun getIslandById() {
        //given
        BDDMockito.given(islandRepository.findOneById("islandId1"))
        .willReturn(IslandEntity(tileList, "1", "islandId1")) //findOneById is my extension function
        //when
        val island = islandService.getIslandById("islandId1")
        //then
        Assertions.assertThat(island?.id).isEqualTo("islandId1")
    }
```

But the preceeding test throws the following error

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
IslandEntity cannot be returned by findById()
findById() should return Optional
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your test should also implement `Optional` as like your source to resolve the issue - Not answering as I'm not aware of Kotlin syntax

Comment: Extension function is a static method which accepts receiver, in your case CrudRepository<T, String>, as a first argument. Therefore Mockito is not able to mock the function call. In order to mock static function, you should use Powermock or some other lib that allows it.

Comment: @TheTechWolf I see. So Mockito does not support this kind of syntax in kotlin out of the box. Is there a workaround maybe to this specific testing scenario? I don't want to use another mocking lib for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in a comment above, in the bytecode extension functions are nothing more than static functions which accept receiver as a first argument. Therefore you can't mock an extension function with a Mockito since it is not able to mock static functions.

What you can do, in case that `findById(id)` is implemented by Repository and not another extension function, is next:

> Mock return value of `findById(id)` instead.

Take a look at the sample code below:

```
@Test
fun getIslandById() {
    //given
    BDDMockito.given(islandRepository.findById("islandId1"))
    .willReturn(Optional.of(IslandEntity(tileList, "1", "islandId1"))) //mock findById function

    //when
    val island = islandService.getIslandById("islandId1")

    //then
    Assertions.assertThat(island?.id).isEqualTo("islandId1")
}
```

This way you are indirectly mocking your extension by providing it a mocked value that you want it to operate on.

Note: Error that you posted above says that your `findById(id)` should return an optional. So, wrap your return value of `findById(id)` function with an optional by calling `Optional.of(result)`.

Comment: Thank you it works. That will do the job for now since there is no other way to trick Mockito into behaving more idiomatically with Kotlin. I will give PowerMock a try soon and see how static methods/extension functions behave there.

Answer (score 2):

Instance extension functions can be mocked like this with a little help of mockito-kotlin:

```kotlin
data class Bar(thing: Int)

class Foo {
   fun Bar.bla(anotherThing: Int): Int { ... }
}

val bar = Bar(thing = 1)
val foo = mock<Foo>()

with(foo) {
  whenever(any<Bar>().bla(any()).doReturn(3)
}

verify(foo).apply {
  bar.bla(anotherThing = 2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround to testing extension methods, suppose you have an scenario like this:

```
class Person {
   public String name;
   public String lastName;
} 

class Extension {
    public static String fullName(Person person, String delimiter) {
       return person.name + delimiter + person.lastName;
    }
 }
```

`Extension.fullName` is just a static method with an instance of the class to be extended as the first parameter, so we could mock it as any other static method

```
@ExtensionMethod({Extension.class})
class CheetahHandlerTest {
    @Test
    void example() {
        User user = new User("Luke", "Skywalker");

        try (MockedStatic<Extension> mockedStatic = mockStatic(Extension.class)) {
            // the mock only works in the scope of the try {}
            mockedStatic.when(() -> Extension.fullName(eq(user), anyString()))
                .thenReturn("Han-Solo");

            assertEquals("Han-Solo", user.fullName("-"));
        }
        assertEquals("Luke-Skywalker", user.fullName("-"));
    }
}
```

The example is very silly but it's good enough to illustrate how we're mocking the fullName function inside of the try.